# How to identifiy if a text is selected in a mx textinput flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

Can any one please tell me how to check whether the text in a mx textinput control is selected or not.I have some controls like mx textinput, mx textara and richtexteditor. selection comes from when user drags it or double click on any control the selection highlights at that time i want to know which control is selected.I have seen the solution for spark textinput which is posted in stackoverflow 
[How to access the selected text in a Flex TextInput control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047150/how-to-access-the-selected-text-in-a-flex-textinput-control) 
but i want for mx components.Please tell me how to know which control text is selected for textinput,textarea and richtexteditor controls.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `TextInput` and `TextArea`:

```
// to check for any selected text:
var hasSelection:Boolean = (component.selectionBeginIndex!=component.selectionEndIndex);
// to get the selected text:
var selection:String = component.text.substring(component.selectionBeginIndex,component.selectionEndIndex);
```

For `RichTextEditor`:

```
// to check for any selected text:
var hasSelection:Boolean = (component.selection.beginIndex!=component.selection.endIndex);
// to get the selected text:
var selection:String = component.selection.text;
```

This will check if the component has any selected text, but not whether the component is selected; the text selection stays *even when the component loses focus*. The easy way to check if the component actually has focus is by setting a boolean flag in the component's `focusIn` and `focusOut` events. You could also deselect the text in a `focusOut` event:

```
component.selectionEndIndex = 0; // clear selection
```

Comment: Hi Cheese thanks for ur answer I did that but the problem is if user didnt do any selection then also selection.endIndex is showing the last character value. so in that case if the text is not selected also returning isSelected as true.But if we select some characters in the textinput selection.endIndex is perfectly working.Any suggestion

Comment: Really? When the user never made any selection, the beginning and end should both be 0. But there are two kinds of "selection" here- I edited my answer to explain better.

Comment: Yes when the user never made any selection i am getting the endindex with the last character from the text in the textinput... Checked again.

Comment: The endIndex is 0 by default for me, on both Flex 3 and Flex 4. Then when the user clicks but does not select, the beginning and end will still be equal. Maybe something else is changing it? Either way, did you try the other part of the solution (dealing with the component focus)?

Comment: ok firstly when i check the textinput the selectionEndIndex is 0 the text came dynamically.Now when i click on the textInput then click outside in the focusout handler i am still seeing the SelectionEndIndex has some value. I tried to set to 0 by giving event.currentTarget.selectionEndIndex = 0 but still it is not assigning the value 0 to the selectionEndIndex property.Did i do anything wrong.Thanks for ur replies.

Comment: Sorry, I can't recreate that problem. Can you set the beginIndex to the endIndex? Did you try using a boolean to keep track of `focusIn` and `focusOut`?

Comment: yes i forcily set endIndex to 0 value but it is not asssigning that value to the endIndex.My requirement is i want to know whether the text in the textinput is selected or not.Is this a bug whenever we click on the text input then without highlighting the text also it is showing selectionEndIndex has some value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12296/discussion-between-trinu-and-cheesewarlock)

Comment: component.selectionBeginIndex!=component.selectionEndIndex is working fine thanks